# Handling undefined case in uniqueness proof (How to Prove It, Velleman; 5.6, 2)

Tags: proof-verification

Below is a theorem I was asked to prove from Velleman's book *How to Prove It*, along with my proof. My question is regarding the last step of the uniqueness portion of the proof where I am required to divide by $(y + 1)$. Since $y$ can be any number, how do I handle the case where $y = -1$? Is this proof still valid in its current form? If not, how would I fix it?

*Theorem.* For every real   number $y$, there is a unique real number $x$ such that   $xy + x - 4 = 4y$.

*Proof.* Let $y$ be an arbitrary real number, and    let $x = 4$. Then
  $$xy + x - 4 = 4y + 4 - 4 = 4y.$$

To see that $x$ is unique, let $z$ be an arbitrary real   number and suppose $zy + z - 4 = 4y$. Then $\
zy + z = 4y + 4$, so $z(y + 1) = 4y + 4$. If $y + 1 = 0$, then $z$ is undefined, but otherwise $z = \
\frac{4y + 4}{y + 1} = 4 = x$.

Comment: If $y=-1$ then every $x$ works, so you do not have uniqueness.

Comment: You say something like: (0,-1), (1,-1) are both in the solution set of $xy + x - 4 = 4y$.  The conjecture is not true for every real $y.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you saw, the case $y=-1$ is special. If $y=-1$ then every $x$ works (just plug into the equation, the left side and right side are both equal to $-4$ for any $x$), so we do not have uniqueness. The "theorem" is false.

Comment: Ah, right! I should have gone back to the original equation and plugged in $y = -1$. Then the "theorem" would have obviously been false. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @jmh: You are welcome. When you reached the stage $z(y+1)=4y+4$, then things naturally break into two cases.  Note the minor typo "$zy+z=4y-4$" in the post.

Comment: Fixed the typo. Thanks again.